Subclassed model not saved by ModelCheckpoint callback
I’m using Keras and TensorFlow 2.12.0 to implement a subclassed model with custom methods, such as a custom train_step. To save the model, I use the ModelCheckpoint callback.
My goal is to save not only the model’s architecture and weights but also the custom methods and training configuration, allowing me to resume training from the exact state where it was left off. From the Keras/TensorFlow documentation, it seems that the HDF5 format can only save the weights of a subclassed model. Therefore, I tried to use the SavedModel and Keras formats. However, after loading the model, the training configuration and custom methods are not available.
Is there something that I might be missing?
Working code snippet to reproduce the issue: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/19tc4EY_wI66ZZBeLlhs0rqIyfQIKENhd?usp=sharing

After some investigation, I realized that since the subclassed model is just a wrapper for training two functional models, I need to:

Explicitly compile the functional models inside the wrapper to save their training configurations.
Override the call function in the wrapper model and explicitly invoke it before saving the subclassed model.

I hope this helps anyone facing the same issue in the future.
